# Silverlight scrolling in RichTextBox

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

Is there a way to scroll, for example, to the start of a RichTextBox from C# code? 
I'm filling its content programmatically (with paragraphs containing images and run texts) and when the filling completes the location of the scroll is at the bottom of RichTextBox. I would like to set it to top, instead of bottom.

I have tried to created a workaround with wrapping my RichTextbox with a ScrollViewer: However when I call its ScrollToVerticalOffset on the ScrollViewer nothing happens, the UI doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reach inside the RichTextBox control to get hold of its internal `ScrollViewer` then call `ScrollToVerticalOffset`.  This is done with the help of `VisualTreeHelper`, see this [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx) for the small source code of a couple of useful extension methods.  With the `VisualTreeEnumeration` class available you can use the following code to get the `ScrollViewer`

```
 ScrollViewer sv = myRichTextBox.Descendents().OfType<ScrollViewer>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This works fine in a case when I click to a button to scroll to the top. However when I try to call the ScrollToVerticalOffset from the same method which fills the RichTextBox nothing happens. In this case, the ScrollViewer's VerticalOffset property just stays 0 but its still on the bottom. How could this be fixed?

Comment: @eric: use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to queue up the scroll bar manipulation in the UI Threads dispatch queue.  This will allow the RichTextBox to sort out its UI before your code comes in to move it.

Answer (score 3):

try
          rtb.Selection.Select(rtb.ContentStart, rtb.ContentStart);
for scroll to start

and
          rtb.Selection.Select(rtb.ContentEnd, rtb.ContentEnd);
for scroll to end

Comment: do note AnthonyWJones's comment under the other reply on using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to schedule the scrolling action if you've just added more text and want to scroll to the bottom